# comparison: after, with

Tags: conjunctions, coordination

1. A second American journalist appears to have been executed by Islamic State militants **after** another chilling video emerged online overnight. (Aussie ABC’s transcript; [part](http://a-thounsand.tistory.com/20) of the audio; [original](http://www.abc.net.au/am/content/2014/s4079731.htm)
2. A second American journalist appears to have been executed by Islamic State militants **with** another chilling video emerging online overnight.  (my transcript)

The audio is not matched with 1 - English sounds being way different from my own, there could be errors. It needs to be corrected *with*, whose semantic meaning is [OLAD #11](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/with). But can ‘*after*’ be used in the same context? Can '*after*' be used to denote a cause for something? If yes, is whose meaning [OLAD #6](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/after_1) -  *as a result of or because of something that has happened*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A journalist appears to have been executed **after** another video **emerged** overnight.
> A journalist appears to have been executed **with** another video **emerging** overnight.

I believe the definitions you chose for *with* and *after* are correct in this context. I would prefer the first sentence because of the simple past tense, which I believe is easier to understand.

The newscasters speak in a way that is meant for television. Instead of saying:

> A video emerged overnight that appears to be the execution of a second American journalist by Islamic State militants.

the newscaster begins the sentence with the most attention getting part—"A second American journalist executed...". This, combined with the desire to speak very concisely to report the most news in the shortest amount of time, causes some very strange sentence structures.